# Webstorm: slow variable inspection (mouse hover) when debugging (Javascript)

Tags: performance, debugging, webstorm

I'm a longtime VisualStudio user and just recently discovered that there is a whole world outside of it - namely node.js - which I find very interesting so I decided to play around with it.

Now I know that there is a node.js plugin for VS but quite frankly - intellisense is somewhere between horrible and non-existent (maybe I'm doing something wrong?).

I am trying out Webstorm which seems to be pretty nice. My only complaint would be that the whole debugging workflow is a little painfull. Everything seems to take much longer than in VS. When a breakpoint is hit and I would like to inspect some local variables (hovering over with the mouse) it always takes about a second until the appropriate tooltip shows up.

Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue (moving to WebStorm 8 feels sluggish and sometimes even flat out non-responsive (e.g. stepping through code)). Any new findings?
BTW, I once saw that you can get better JS intellisense in VS by adding the source file as a comment at the top of the file (but not sure whether this still works and if it is documented).

Answer (score 0):

Please can you check if the problem persists in [WebStorm 9 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+9+EAP)? It includes some improvements related to node debugging performance

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Nope - unfortunately the behavior is the same... Hit a breakpoint, move mouse over local variable (e.g. 'res' input parameter of route handler). Then hold the mouse still about one second until the tooltip finally shows... Is this supposed to be instant?